# What is Node.js........... Where it's been used...... And what is the usage of it........?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, npm

Sometime back when I was at learning pace at IBM..... I get to know something called `BlueMix` which is cloud product...... In that I've seen some primitive component so called `Node.js`...... Since then I was curious to know about it.....

But it was quite unfortunate that whomsoever I talk, Industry Folks lacks to give an idea about it.....

Please get me to know the things on & around of `Node.js`.......... I've used `prototype.js` and learnt `JQuery` and more out of product of `.js` vass in the industry....

Please let me know what is `Node.js`..... What for it is.....?

Comment: Node.js is a JavaScript based server program.

Comment: [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) is a platform/runtime/environment rather than a library (like prototype.js and jQuery). It uses [Google's V8 JavaScript Engine](https://code.google.com/p/v8) and adds some of [its own APIs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/). Its intention is to allow you to define console and server applications using the JavaScript language. It's also extensible, with a [collection of packages](https://www.npmjs.com/) already available to use with it.

Answer (score 1):

One day, a dude named Ryan Dahl forked Chrome's V8 engine, which is arguably the most advanced and the fastest javascript engine as of today. He modified it a little, so it could do stuff like emit and receive HTTP requests. He put it on a server and voila, he got a javascript server (server-side javascript) and gave it a weird name ("node.js").

So basically, it replaces a PHP, Python or Java server, and it's low level.

Advantages :

- It's super light and super optimized (thanks to Google's engineering for V8)
- It's asynchronous (because Javascript is asynchronous), unlike PHP
- You use only one language for the front-end and for the back-end, everything is JS

Comment: I understand by this, browser's say,- `Stop Running Javascript,- YES||NO` never happens so as its run by server-node or by cloud-computing..... but does this `non-blocking` & `blocking` IO is by any norms just as like `java-security-policies`..... because when it comes to java without required policy entry,- server-side execution by a client initiated program is not possible...... it can be network-client, `applet` or some like so.... I hope `Google V8 Javascript Engine` covers security aspects by so!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the confusion for newcomers to Node is misunderstanding exactly what it is.
An important thing to realize is that Node is not a webserver. By itself it doesn't do anything. It doesn't work like Apache. There is no config file where you point it to you HTML files. If you want it to be a HTTP server, you have to write an HTTP server (with the help of its built-in libraries). Node.js is just another way to execute code on your computer. It is simply a JavaScript runtime.Its an asynchronus library used to serve as server-side.

Comment: Perhaps it is not as like Apache this `Node.js` is mostly used by `cloud-product` by software giants where they ensures and encomprises `PAAS, IAAS, SAAS` and many things into one..... And say it is cloud ready........ `Node.js`,- gives the capability that,- `cloud` needs.... In fact in `IBM Blue Mix` it is a one of the first-line-component in order......!

Answer (score -1):

I understood today, that `Node.js` is a,

> C Program.

Supposedly bound with the C program, although it is `.js` & without its server-side counterpart,- portion of the `javascript` written to, that giving compliance to `Node.js` will not work supposedly by web through web or by cloud node.

Just because it has extension `.js`..... it slightly been misunderstood that it is `javascript`,- rather component..... Although it is, by which `javascript` can be coded to it..... `Node.js` is basically bound by its server side component and has a noble capability scope beyond of its by execution.....

It can be installed by `Node Package Manager` of `unix`

`~$npm install node-static`

and any typical `javascript` compliance to `Node.js` could run by,

```
~$ #in console
~$ node main.js
```

with that your `node` on `cloud` is ready to do any `blocking` & `non-blocking` IO ready by `server-side-javascript-execution`.....

> source: OSFY Magazine

Earlier days `javascript` ability been used by some emulators like `Rhino` at server boxes as independent programs like any typical higher level language programs.....

Comment: `JQuery` is ready made W3C compliance engine for any web platform, wherein `Node.js` needs its counterpart engine ready to be there at..... By this distinguishing mechanism one could understand easily over & above....!